No main manifest attribute in Docker
When I run a local application it runs successfully but when I run the docker container it displays this message in title.
The application is made in Kotlin, and would be a simple authentication with jwt token. I can generate the image more at the time of execution after this command:
docker run -p 3080:8080 application

displays the message:

"No main manifest attribute in Docker"

Local I use jdk 21 which worked
In the dockerfile I built it with this jdk
FROM chainguard/jdk-lts
EXPOSE 8080
ADD /target/application-SNAPSHOT.jar.original application.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "forum.jar"]

Why does it work locally and not in the container?
